# How many bastards are there in GoT?

Tags: game-of-thrones

*Game of Thrones* is full of bastards. And, their existence even drives the main plot.

How many known bastards have been shown on-screen in GoT?

Comment: [books wiki](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Category:Bastards), [show wiki](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Bastards)

Comment: @Aegon funny how show wiki exclude Jon Snow from the list

Comment: @Kepotx Well it is correct by doing so.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot But then incorrect by leaving Ramsay on it... so yeah, typical show wiki. (unless they are saying Jon wasn't even _born_ one while Ramsay still was)

Comment: @Skooba I would imagine that is the difference they were going for.

Comment: While he is not technically a bastard, this information is not revealed yet to everyone in-universe, so everyone considers Jon Snow as a bastard, same as everyone considered Joffrey, Tommen and Myrcella as true born

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Game of Thrones wiki](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Bastards) there are 12-18 that we see on screen.

#### Jon Snow

A bastard in name and a bastard throughout the most of the show in Season 7 Episode 7 he is revealed to be true born and so may not count.

#### Ramsay <s>Snow</s> Bolton

A bastard throughout his introduction to the show but is later legitimised.

#### Barra

One of Robert Baratheon's bastards that Cersei has killed in Season 1.

#### Craster

The wiki makes mention of Craster as a bastard so I am including him here but I'm not sure if he is one or not.

#### Jafer Flowers

One of the rangers of the Night's Watch in Season 1 that accompanies Benjen Stark beyond the Wall and is brought back to Castle Black as a wight.

#### Gendry

The master rower is one of Robert Baratheon's bastards who appears multiple times throughout the show but escapes Cersei's anger in Season 1.

#### Donnel Hill

A man of the Night's Watch who is killed under the Wall defending it from the giant in the Battle of Castle Black.

#### Ryger Rivers

One of Walder Frey's many bastards.

#### Walder Rivers

One of Walder Frey's many bastards.

#### Daemon Sand

Oberyn Martell's squire during his head popping ceremony.

#### Ellaria Sand

The leader of the Sand Snakes and Oberyn Martell's paramour.

#### Nymeria Sand

A Sand Snake.

#### Obara Sand

A Sand Snake.

#### Tyene Sand

A Sand Snake.

#### Samwell Stone

A knight in service of House Royce.

#### Joffrey, Myrcella and Tommen Baratheon

Whilst they are named the true born of Robert Baratheon and Cersei Lannister they are actually Cersei and Jaime Lannister's children and so are bastards.

Comment: In the scene where the gold cloaks kill a bunch of children (S2E1?) couldn't they all be counted as well? I suppose we don't know for sure that they are Robert's bastards but it seems likely.